# What does "you can rule over it" in Genesis 4.7 mean?

Tags: sin

In Gensis 4.7 we read (in relationship to Cain and Abel and ruling over sin)
"If thou doest well, shall it not be lifted up? and if thou doest not well, sin coucheth at the door; and unto thee is its desire, but thou mayest rule over it."

What is meant by "but thou mayest rule over it?"

The Hebrew text reads,  וְאַתָּה, תִּמְשָׁל-בּוֹ. (ve'atah ti'meshal bo) and the Strong's says mashal means to rule, have dominion, reign.

It appears that from this text Cain could *rule over sin*, that is, he had a choice to rule over his evil inclination.

Comment: it seems that you have the right understanding of "thou mayest rule over it", that "he had a choice to rule over his evil inclination." What remains unclear to you? perhaps you should edit this question!

Comment: Good question. Up-voted.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see the manuscripts stating the rule being over *sin*. This is what I find:

From the Westminster Leningrad Codex Genesis 4:7:

> **הֲלוֹא אִם־תֵּיטִיב שְׂאֵת וְאִם לֹא תֵיטִיב לַפֶּתַח חַטָּאת רֹבֵץ וְאֵלֶי תְּשׁוּקָתוֹ וְאַתָּה תִּמְשָׁל־בּוֹ**
>
> *hálô im-Tëy†iyv s'ët w'im lo tëy†iyv laPetach cha‡ät rovëtz w'ëleykhä T'shûqätô w'aTäh Tim'shäl-Bô*

**Transliteration:**
?·not if you-are-doing-good to-lift-up-of and·if not you-are-doing-good to·the·portal sin-offering reclining and·to·you impulse-of·him and·you you-are-ruling in·him

**The text appears to say:** *because you desire sin he will rule you -**OR**- Because you desire sin your rule will be through him. **NOT** you will rule sin/him*

This statement from verse 7 reads like: *you rule yourself in goodness or in sin, either way you are ruling, so you're accountable*. Which is why in verse 6 YHWH is asking Cain:

> And the LORD said unto
> Cain, Why art thou wroth?
> and why is thy countenance
> fallen?

YHWH asks Cain why he's upset with YHWH rather than himself, and in verse 7 YHWH explains to Cain, it's all under your control, you rule yourself through goodness or through sin.

Comment: Good answer....1 caveat. Who is the "he" who will rule over you if you sin?

Comment: I don't need the Westminster Leningrad Codex. The Hebrew text is what matters to me

Comment: @YochananMauritzHummasti, without autographa, what do you use to read the Hebrew text?

Comment: @Tau, you'd have to employ systematic theology to extract meanings and principles that are not available in a specific text. I would say Satan, given the context and the topic.

Comment: it's simple there is a Sefer Torah (Torah Scroll) and there are Chumashim (The Five Books of the Torah in written [book] form with the commentaries of, for instance Rashi. I don't read christian text as they are erronious )

Comment: @YochananMauritzHummasti, my friend the Leningrad codex is the surviving form of the Torah Scroll in the Tanakh. A Sifrei Torah is a handwritten copy of the Torah scroll for synagogues. Is what you meant to say that you're not sure what the Leningrad Codex is?

Comment: I don't concern myself with the Christian intepretations of the Leningrad Codex. I have the Sefer Torah and the Chumash to read from with the Rabbinical Commentaries to supplement my own readings.

Comment: @YochananMauritzHummasti, your superiority is noted. Could you share with me a verse from Bereshit that is not in or different from Leningrad Codex to Seifer Torah?

Comment: whay ask such a question

Comment: @YochananMauritzHummasti - If I am not mistaken, the so-called Leningrad Codex was produced by Jews, not Christians.  In any case, if you have access to and trust in Rashi's commentaries, why are you asking the question here? [According to Rashi](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8168#showrashi=true), "but you can rule over it" means "If you wish, you will overpower it."  From your comments, perhaps Mi Yodeya would be a better fit for you.  It seems someone has posed a [similar question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85291/genesis-47-timshol-bo) there.

Comment: I would prefer the The Aleppo Codex

Comment: @YochananMauritzHummasti I consulted the Rashi, because the "ruling over" of the evil inclination seems to be included; but the text used does not appear to be in agreement with the Strongs(which uses the KJV), in which case I viewed the Leningrad Codex-which is the Masoretic Text in complete form(the Aleppo is incomplete). I fear the HB  uses certain Targums, which I've found 'corrupted' in several instances. Strongs relies heavily on the Masoretic text-and the Keil and Delitzsch Commentary, though "Christian" uses the Masoretic.

Comment: @user33515 great points.

Comment: What is the HB? I presume you are referring to the Hebrew Bible, (which my fellow Jews call the Tanak). What kind of authority or who are you to say that the Targums are "corrupted"?

Comment: @YochananMauritzHummasti, *Tanakh. I find it strange that you seem to hold yourself in such high regards as a literary expert yet you dismiss historically strong texts and seem to have no knowledge of sourcing. Rather than having the capacity to educate, you are dismissive and make only assertions. Your assertions are unfounded and entirely unsupported by your inability to dialogue and make meaningful statements in defense or in opposition. I'd love to hear your perspective but I fear you have only pretentious presuppositions and limited reference. I hope you prove me wrong.

Comment: My sources are exclusively Jewish

Answer (score 1):

The Previous answer spells out the grammatical equivalent of what is being stated: rather "mashal" is indicating who has rule over you.

From Keil and Delitzsch's Commentary:

> "Why art thou wroth, and why is thy countenance fallen?" The answer to
>   this is given in the further question, "Is there not, if thou art
>   good, a lifting up" (sc., of the countenance)? It is evident from the
>   context, and the antithesis of falling and lifting up (נפל and נשׂא),
>   that פּנים must be supplied after שׂאת. By this God gave him to
>   understand that his look was indicative of evil thoughts and
>   intentions; for the lifting up of the countenance, i.e., a free, open
>   look, is the mark of a good conscience (Job 11:15). "But if thou art
>   not good, sin lieth before the door, and its desire is to thee
>   (directed towards thee); but thou shouldst rule over it." The fem.
>   חטּאת is construed as a masculine, because, with evident allusion to
>   the serpent, sin is personified as a wild beast, lurking at the door
>   of the human heart, and eagerly desiring to devour his soul (1 Peter
>   5:8). היטיב, to make good, signifies here not good action, the
>   performance of good in work and deed, but making the disposition good,
>   i.e., directing the heart to what is good. Cain is to rule over the
>   sin which is greedily desiring him, by giving up his wrath, not indeed
>   that sin may cease to lurk for him, but that the lurking evil foe may
>   obtain no entrance into his heart. There is no need to regard the
>   sentence as interrogative, "Wilt thou, indeed, be able to rule over
>   it?" (Ewald), nor to deny the allusion in בּו to the lurking sin, as
>   Delitzsch does. The words do not command the suppression of an inward
>   temptation, but resistance to the power of evil as pressing from
>   without, by hearkening to the word which God addressed to Cain in
>   person, and addresses to us through the Scriptures.

What is expressed is by his anger, he is allowing evil(Satan) to rule over him, whereas by restraining his impulse, he continues to remain in fellowship with God. The individual bears the consequence for his actions, as the previous author states, but it is "who' rules over you which determines your "mashal".

Comment: +1) I appreciate this contribution. However, the way you handle 'mashal' I do not understand why or how you come to an implied need to treat it this way. In this instance, the mashal is accessed  through another agent "rule through him". It seems your using mashal as lordship. Can you help me understand this?

Comment: King David said in 1 Chronicles 29.12 and Thou rulest over all; in this context mashal means to "rule over" as in absolute rule - whatever third person agent you are referring makes no sense whatsoever. either one can rule over sin or not

Comment: The "mashal" is 1st used on Gen. 3:16, "he shall "yimsal/mashal" over you. God gave Adam the command "to rule/have dominion" over his wife. It is God's authority that makes this possible, not Adam's ability to subjugate Eve. Adam is ruling, yet Eve understands it's God's rule, not Adam's 'whim'. But when Cain allows his anger and envy to get the best of him, Satan makes use of his anger to incite Cain to murder. Both Adam and Cain are responsible for their actions, but the desire of God is they would respond to His influence, and not Satan's.

Comment: To "sin" is to disobey God; in thought, word, and action. There is no "neutral" position. Whatever influences you causes you to sin, to "rule over sin" is to obey God who certainly influences to do well. Conversely, to sin is allow the evil one(Satan) to rule over you, and influence your behavior.

Comment: In Isaiah 45:7, we see that Hashem is the creator of everything, as the text says, “bringing forth light and create darkness, I make peace and create evil, I am G-D who does all these things.” G-D (HaShem) always gives a person the freedom to choose between the yetzer tov and the yetzer hara (the inclination to good or evil). The evil one (Satan) is merely an agent of HaShem who is an enticer of evil. Ultimately it is HaShem (G-D) who gives the adversary permission to entice or to influence people as in Job chapter 1. Only G-D is Mashal - Satan has no rule over anything he is HaShem's servant!

Comment: @YochananMauritzHummasti 1) The Isa. 45:7 passage "בּוֺרֵא רָ֑ע"(BDB) in the noun form translates evil as "calamity", certainly a result of sin(witness Deut. 28:15-68) yet in no way can attribute "evil" to God-who is All Good. That God gives every person a choice, and holds them accountable is a given; to call "ha-Satan"(the Opposer) as God's servant, when God Himself cursed him in the Garden(Gen. 3:14-15), and describes his fall from Heaven(Isa. 14:12/Ezek. 28:14-19) is not a valid description. Yes, Satan exists, and causes evil; he is 'allowed' for this time. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) In the Book of Enoch he comes to his destruction; and in the book of Revelations he is cast into hell. The fact that he somehow 'appears' before God in Job doesn't give him a 'position' in God's court: God certainly 'allowed' him to tempt Job, as he is 'allowed' to tempt us. That makes him a tempter, not a servant. Nor does it make God "helpless" in the face of evil, witness the many times God delivers Israel, their prophets, and servants in the face of evil. And in Job's case, his latter end was much greater than the former, when God restored everything and more to Job.

Comment: (Finally) That a man 'succumbs' to temptation gives the "tempter" permission to rule his life. This is why idols are destroyed; they represent the work of the evil one, they invite the evil presence in, and they create a "demonic stronghold" which caused destruction, even after righteous kings destroyed the idols. If an idol were merely the work of a man's hands, they would just be discarded-the fact is they introduced behaviors and practices that were contrary to God's Law told of a power they possessed-which was the power of evil.

Comment: And here Jews and Christians differ. If you want to believe in talking serpents that fall from heaven go ahead. (what do you mean, witness Deut. 28:15-68?) I can demonstrate from Exodus 12:23 that HaShem is Mashal over the "destroyer." Clearly we can deduce from Iyov (Job) 1.12 that satan can only do what HaShem (The L-RD) allows. "And the L-RD said unto Satan: 'Behold, all that he hath is in thy power; only upon himself put not forth thy hand.' So Satan went forth from the presence of the L-RD." Iyov (Job) 1.12

Comment: @YochananMauritzHummasti God punishes wrongdoing-the curses (calamity) spelled out in Deut. 28 illustrate that. Yes, Christians and Jews do differ in their understanding of Satan, but the prophets were understanding of who he was(the Isa. 14:12/Ezek. 28:14-19) passage confirm that. Even the 1 Kings 22:22 confirm the Lord is not the Author of evil, though He allowed the lying spirit to prevail in the mouths of the false prophets. The false prophets 'succumbed' to the temptation of the lying spirit-clearly a messenger of Satan. Their 'reward' was to meet destruction(vs 25).

Comment: that is a false understanding of Isaiah 14. where it reads morning star" (lucifer is a name found is nowhere in the Jewish Bible. you are reading from a translation). Clearly, 14.16 reads  'Is this "the man" that made the earth to tremble,....' (emphasis supplied) explain "the man" in 14.16. Ezekiel 28 has nothing to do with the Adversary (haSatan); (it discusses the merchavah mysteries, something only taught to mystics). Don't misquote 1 Kings 22 and skip over the verse which says "and the L-RD hath spoken evil concerning thee.'" As far as curses, your Xtian scripture says Jesus is a curse

Comment: @YochananMauritzHummasti Hi Yochanan, if you would agree, I would like to move this discussion to chat. It's apparent that it has gone far beyond the meaning of "mashal", although clearly it remains the central focus. We can be more freer in expanding our understandings....OK?

Comment: @YochananMauritzHummasti this is not a Jewish-christian debating forum, this is strictly about biblical hermeneutics. You have anything intelligent to say go ahead. If your here to show superiority in Jewish over christian sources and commentary your not welcome here. As Tau already pointed out Mi Yodeya might be more suitable for you! Besides, finding fault in posts other users worked hard on to answer your question is not very smart, you will only turn away others from coming near you in the future!

Comment: @Tau nowhere in B'rashith (Genesis) 3.14-15 did HaShem curse "the adversary" (haSatan). It is true that HaShem did curse the serpent (Nachash) but the Torah reveals what the punishment was (on your belly...dust shall you eat). It was not being cast down from heaven as you allege!

Comment: @Tau Christians claim that because Adam and Chavvah (Eve) sinned in Gan Eden mankind was cursed with a "sin nature" but the Torah says otherwise: "cursed is haAdamah" (3.17, but compare 8.21). The Torah's use of the word "mashal" is telling us we have "freedom of choice" as is clear from Deut. 30, Joshua 24 & Ezekiel 18.

Answer (score 0):

In this text of rule over sin, our creator is telling us we are like kings we can rule everything and anything. He giving us the power to rule over sin. We have this dominion and we can use it, and he warn us that sin is close by  ir in our path where we going. We can make go away or we become slaves or sin. In this yhwh is not saying the adversary is crunching @ the door, he saying “sin” is crunching meaning we know is there is up to us to rule over it.. when we let sin over rule us! We give the adversary take over our thoughts and move forward with sin. We desire sin. Sin don’t desire us we have the power to rule knowing is there our choice is our we desire to sin or not to sin is our prerogative. The adversary is just waiting for us to make the decision to sin and he will give us the tools to go for it. In egg shell we are like kings hid say you ca over rule sin. It’s our desire to comply. Bless be the naming our creator yhawe. To hi his the glory for ever amen let’s rule sin because we can over rule sin god give us the power to rule sin.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics. We look for well researched answers that provide evidence to support claims made. When you have a moment, please take our Tour to find out how we are different to other sites: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).